# Spring OAuth2 - ensure call to OAuth2ProtectedResourceFilter

Tags: servlets, spring-mvc, spring-security

How do I ensure that a call is being made to the OAuth2ProtectedResourceFilter when a request is sent with the oauth_token in the Authorization header?

Answer (score 0):

It always passes through a filter if it is mapped properly

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, everything that you want to be secured, needs to go through a spring security filter:

Here a sample how a filter is mapped in front of the servlet (the spring MVC DispatcherServlet used for the authorization endpoints)
You could additionally map the same filter to any other servlet, for example to a `jersey` servlet you have configured.

In **/WEB-INF/web.xml** you need a **filter-mapping** like:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

To **ensure** every call to '/*', or whatever pattern, is filtered you use `http` from the spring security namespace and a filter called **OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter**, that will watch out for the *Bearer* Authorization header, you will need something like this in your */WEB-INF/spring-mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml* or where ever your spring security is configured:

```
<http pattern="/**" 
      create-session="never" 
      authentication-manager-ref="userAuthenticationManager"
      access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" 
      use-expressions="true">

    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <custom-filter ref="oAuth2AuthenticationFilter" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oAuthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />        
</http>

<beans:bean id="oAuth2AuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="userAuthenticationManager"/>
    <beans:property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="oAuthAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
</beans:bean>
```